# ModelMapper incorrectly maps to nested object property

Tags: java, modelmapper

I am using ModelMapper to map DTOs to Entities and vice versa. I have a problem when a I am mapping a `ChildDTO` to a `Child` where both the `Child` class and the `Parent` class have a property with the same name.

These are the objects:

```java
public class Child {

    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name; // <---- property called 'name'
    // other properties

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
}

public class Parent {

    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name; // <---- property called 'name'
    // other properties

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> items = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class ChildDTO {

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    // other properties

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Long parentId;
}
```

And this is the code that does the mapping:

```java
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setAmbiguityIgnored(true);
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

Child childItem = repository.findById(id);

ChildDTO childItemDTO = new ChildDTO();
childItemDTO.setName("new name");

modelMapper.map(childItemDTO, childItem);
```

This results in **both** `Child::name` **and** `Parent::name` to change to "new name". Notice I'm already using the `STRICT` mapping strategy.

I could also not find way of skipping calling `Parent::setName()` when mapping from `ChildDTO` to `Child`

ModelMapper version: 2.3.2

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue on a simplified demo project (http://jdoodle.com/a/1FUP). Are you sure there's not something else in your program that triggers this behavior?

Comment: You are right, I don't understand why the mapping happens in my case, but it can be seen in the `typeMap.getMappings()` result [here](https://imgur.com/a/Y3rsilp). This also seems to happen inconsistently - on some runs it works correctly. I will try to dive into the ModelMapper code deeper

Comment: OK - I have modified your JDoodle [here](http://jdoodle.com/a/1FZd) and it seems that it happens when the `MatchingStrategy` is not `STRICT` and the names of the Parent class (`CodeTemplate`) and the Child class (`CodeTemplateItem`) overlap somehow - if I change the names back to `Parent` and `Child` the issue does not occur. We switch between `STRICT` and `STANDARD` mode for the same `ModelMapper` instance and that seems to be the problem - the `TypeMap` must have been created and cached while in `STANDARD` mode, so switching modes later has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a challenge where Model Mapper attempted to map nested fields with the same abstract class as the parent, resulting in the engine mapping values to the child properties. To address this issue, I devised a solution by extending the matching strategy to avoid mapping unexpected nested fields.
example :

```
abstract class AbstractClass{
    String ref;
}

class Parent extends AbstractClass{
    ...
    
}

class Child extends AbstractClass{
    Parent parent;
    ...
}
```

when i try to map a Child object whith this data

{
ref: "CHILD-REF";
parent: null
}
to another Child object
{
ref: null,
parent: {
ref: "PARENT-REF"
}
}

the beahvior by default will be a Child object :
{
ref: "CHILD-REF",
parent: {
ref: "CHILD-REF"
}
}

and using my new condition the result will be
{
ref: "CHILD-REF",
parent: {
ref: "PARENT-REF"
}
}

here the details

```
...
final ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
...
mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(new CustomModelMapperMapping());
```

extending the MatchingStrategies.STANDARD

```
public class CustomModelMapperMapping implements MatchingStrategy {

    static final MatchingStrategy standardMatchingStrategy = MatchingStrategies.STANDARD;

    NuagikeModelMapperMapping() {
    }

    public boolean matches(PropertyNameInfo propertyNameInfo) {

        //this is the strandard behavior
        final boolean standard_matching_result = standardMatchingStrategy.matches(propertyNameInfo);
        
        //and then i added new condition
        if (standard_matching_result) {

            final String sourceSubTokens = propertyNameInfo.getSourcePropertyTokens()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(s -> StreamSupport.stream(s.spliterator(), false))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("-")).toLowerCase();
            final String destinationSubTokens = propertyNameInfo.getDestinationPropertyTokens()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(s -> StreamSupport.stream(s.spliterator(), false))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("-")).toLowerCase();

            return sourceSubTokens.equals(destinationSubTokens);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean isExact() {
        return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "my custom strategy";
    }
}
```